# Change TextView Value inside Custom ListView Android by onclick

Tags: android, listview

I have custom listview that contains various textview and imageview....Now I want to change the value of the textview on the list based onclick.

So I use this code as suggested

```
jam = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date());

    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            TextView plg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.idJamPlg);
            plg.setText(jam);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

It changed the value but I noticed something when I scrolled the view. The value of the next view after scrolled has also changed. So if I have like 10 lists and only 3 that is visible on the screen, when I click the first list it will change the value of the 1st list then also change the value of the 5th one.
Any idea why this happen?
Thanks

Comment: if you have used view holder, this problem is due to that as android reuses the previously created views.

Comment: If you have used BaseAdapter for your list then you have to setTag for your views in getView() method.

Comment: @Bhavnik Im using SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: @M.Ashish Im not sure understand that,,, but Im using AdapterView as u can see

Comment: Can you show me how you setAdapter to your listview ?

Comment: @Bhavnik if u mean assign adapter to listview, its like above code listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

Comment: `SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                getActivity(), R.layout.daftar_row,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);`